# getElementsByClassName('any')[multiply]

Tags: javascript

возможно ли такое, чтобы в 1 строку уместить сразу несколько значений? 
Ex: getElementsByClassName('any')[0,1]

В примере ниже осуществлен алерт, по нажатию верхней буквы, но мне бы хотелось чтобы одно и тоже действие на две буквы, выполняла одна строчка кода.

И если можно, после этого сделать так, чтобы эта функция выполнялась лишь единожды на запущенной странице, т.е. в последующем чтобы работала так же единоразово лишь после перезагрузки страницы.
[image]

```js
(function () {
    $('#f, #p').addClass('testing');
    var test = document.getElementsByClassName('testing')[0];
    test.onclick = function () {
        alert('232');
    };
}());
```

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<a id="f">F.</a><br>
<a id="p">P.</a><br>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var flag = true;

[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (flag) {
      alert('Hello, world');
      flag = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a id="f">F.</a><br>
  <a id="p">P.</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как обозначается данная запись ? `[...document.querySelectorAll('a')]`

Comment: Большое спасибо, это в большей части решило мою проблему, но все же хотелось бы узнать возможно ли какое-либо схожее употребление данному: 
getElementsByClassName('any')[0,1] ?

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE, выбрать и занести в массив все `a`

Comment: @SkyLikeIT, если Вы хотите на определенные `a` повешать что-то, то лучше дайте им какой-нибудь класс-модификатор, а потом выбирайте все элементы этого класса и добавляйте события.

Comment: @meine, хорошо, еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE это spread оператор